# TypeScript : Generic type with primitive types constrain

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have the following generic classes in TypeScript

```
type UserId = number
type Primitive = string | number | boolean
class ColumnValue<T, S extends Primitive> {
    constructor(public columnName: String, public value: S) { }
}
abstract class Column<T> {
    constructor(public columnName: String) { }
    public set<S extends Primitive>(value: T): ColumnValue<T, S> {
        return new ColumnValue(this.columnName, this.getValue(value))
    }
    public abstract getValue<S extends Primitive>(value: T): S
}
let id = new class extends Column<UserId> {
    constructor() { super("id") }
    public getValue(value: UserId): number {
        return value
    }
}()
```

But I don't know why get this error:

```
Class '(Anonymous class)' incorrectly extends base class 'Column<number>'.
  Types of property 'getValue' are incompatible.
    Type '(value: number) => number' is not assignable to type '<S extends Primitive>(value: number) => S'.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'S'
```

Comment: May be you have to define S in a concrete manner. S extends boolean, but what is it really?

Comment: @jaibatrik I edit my question maybe it is more clear now,  I want ts compiler infer value type in **ColumnValue class** and make sure it is **Primative type**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On `Column` getter and setter `S` isn't necessarily the same type so you should move the type param to its parent class: `Column<T, S extends Primitive>`.

```
type UserId = number
type Primitive = string | number | boolean
class ColumnValue<T, S extends Primitive> {
    constructor(public columnName: String, public value: S) { }
}
abstract class Column<T, S extends Primitive> {
    constructor(public columnName: String) { }
    public set(value: T): ColumnValue<T, S> {
        return new ColumnValue(this.columnName, this.getValue(value))
    }
    public abstract getValue(value: T): S
}
let id = new class extends Column<UserId, number> {
    constructor() { super("id") }
    public getValue(value: UserId): number {
        return value
    }
}()
```

The version above [has no errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20UserId%20%3D%20number%0D%0Atype%20Primitive%20%3D%20string%20%7C%20number%20%7C%20boolean%0D%0Aclass%20ColumnValue%3CT%2C%20S%20extends%20Primitive%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20columnName%3A%20String%2C%20public%20value%3A%20S)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Aabstract%20class%20Column%3CT%2C%20S%20extends%20Primitive%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor(public%20columnName%3A%20String)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20set(value%3A%20T)%3A%20ColumnValue%3CT%2C%20S%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20new%20ColumnValue(this.columnName%2C%20this.getValue(value))%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20abstract%20getValue(value%3A%20T)%3A%20S%0D%0A%7D%0D%0Alet%20id%20%3D%20new%20class%20extends%20Column%3CUserId%2C%20number%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20constructor()%20%7B%20super(%22id%22)%20%7D%0D%0A%20%20%20%20public%20getValue(value%3A%20UserId)%3A%20number%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20return%20value%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D()) at least.

I understand that you probably want to infer the `S` from whatever type you use with you setter but `Column` must have a well defined type upon instantiation, so that means that you either explicit when calling the constructor (that is `new Column<UserId, number>(...)`) or add a `S` param in the constructor so `S` can be inferred from it (like in `new Column<UserId>('id', 123)`)

Comment: thanks, but is it a compiler error, or there is a logical meaning about infer `S`

Answer (score 1):

Your `getValue` uses a generic `S`, so, the inherited implementation must use `S` as well.

```
let id = new class extends Column<UserId> {
    constructor() { super("id") }
    public getValue<S extends Primative>(value: UserId): S {
        return <S>value
    }
}()
```

If you take the `S` to the class, your function can be narrowed to `number`.

```
abstract class Column<T, S extends Primative> {
    constructor(public columnName: String) { }
    public set(value: T): ColumnValue<T, S> {
        return new ColumnValue(this.columnName, this.getValue(value))
    }
    public abstract getValue(value: T): S
}

let id = new class extends Column<UserId, UserId> {
    constructor() { super("id") }
    public getValue(value: UserId): number {
        return value
    }
}()
```