# Typescript generic constrain

Tags: typescript

I am trying to write a generic getter function, given a key which should only return the type string|boolean|number. The default value should therefore be of the same type as the returned value

Here is what I have tried.

```
getSomething = async<T extends string | boolean | number>
    (key: string, defaultValue: T): Promise<T> => {
      const foo = bar.getValue("foo"); // return type is undefined|string|boolean|number
      return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo;
 }
```

I get this error, not sure what is wrong.

```
Type 'string | number | boolean | T' is not assignable to type 'T'.
  'string | number | boolean | T' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | boolean'.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'T'.
      'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string | number | boolean'.ts(2322)
```

What could possibly be a subtype of 'string | number | boolean' is what puzzled me. Aren't they already a primitive type?

Comment: Example of when this would be wrong: `getSomething<string>('key', 'default')`. Here function should return `string`, but `string|boolean|number` is returned.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [typescript : generic type with primitive types constrain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46387138/typescript-generic-type-with-primitive-types-constrain)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without the definition of `bar` this isn't a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Since all I know is that `bar.getValue()` returns a value of type `string | number | boolean | undefined`, I will make my own `bar` like this:

```
const bar = { getValue: (x: string): string | number | boolean | undefined => 12345 };
```

Then I write this code, which has no compiler errors:

```
const str = Math.random().toString();
getSomething("baz", str).then(v => console.log(v.toUpperCase()));
```

If you inspect the type of `v` with IntelliSense in your TypeScript IDE, it will be  `string`.  That's because the call signature of `getSomething()` says that it will return a promise of the same type as the second parameter.  We passed in `str`, a `string`, so we get a `Promise<string>` out, right?

Oops, nope.  Run the code and you'll get a runtime error and a message like `TypeError: v.toUpperCase is not a function`.  Because at runtime, `v` will be `12345`, the actual value returned from `bar.getValue()`.  And `12345` is a `number`, which has no `toUpperCase` method.   Somehow we got into a situation where a `number` was mistaken for a `string`.  Where was the mistake?

It's exactly where the compiler warned you:

```
return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo; // error!
// Type 'string | number | boolean | T' is not assignable to type 'T'.
```

TypeScript is telling you that you are supposed to be returning a value of type `T`, but the compiler can only verify that you are returning a value of type `string | number | boolean | T`.  In the case above, `T` was `string`, so you can interpret the error as something like "you're claiming to return a `string` but all I know is that you're returning a `string | number | boolean`, which *might* be a `string` but maybe it's a `number` or a `boolean` in which case your claim is incorrect and bad things might happen".

Hopefully you understand why this is a problem.  `T` can be `string` or `number` or `boolean`, which are all *narrower* than the union type `string | number | boolean`.  You can assign `T` to `string | number | boolean` but not vice versa.

---

About this question: "What could possibly be a subtype of `string | number | boolean` is what puzzled me. Aren't they already a primitive type?"  Well, `string` is a subtype of `string | number | boolean`.  A union `A | B` is a supertype of each of its members `A` and `B`.

Furthermore, even if you just had `string` or `number` or `boolean`, there are subtypes of these in TypeScript: there are [string literal types](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#string-literal-types) like the *type* `"foo"`, [numeric literal types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) like the *type* `123`, and even boolean literal types `true` and `false` (mentioned [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#better-inference-for-literal-types) and probably other places).  These literal types represent specific values.  So the types `"a"` and `"b"` are subtypes of `string`, and the types `1` and `2` are subtypes of `number`, and the types `true` and `false` are subtypes of `boolean`.

So in fact, when you call `getSomething()` with the second parameter as a string, numeric, or boolean literal, that's what gets inferred for `T`:

```
const p = getSomething("qux", "peanut butter and jelly");
// const p: Promise<"peanut butter and jelly">
```

So not only does `p` represent a promise of a string (which is not true in general), it actually represents a promise for the *specific* string `"peanut butter and jelly"`.  Oops.

---

So how do we fix this code?  Well, that depends strongly on your use case.  At first glance I'd say maybe it shouldn't be generic at all, and just allow both input and output to be `string | number | boolean`:

```
const getSomething2 = async (key: string, defaultValue: string | number | boolean):
    Promise<string | number | boolean> => {
    const foo = bar.getValue("foo"); 
    return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo;
}
```

That compiles with no error, and then the earlier code that had a runtime error but no compiler error now gives you a nice compiler error:

```
getSomething2("baz", str).then(v => console.log(v.toUpperCase())); // error!
// ---------------------------------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~
// Property 'toUpperCase' does not exist on type 'number'.
```

The value `v` is now known to be `string | number | boolean`, and you can't call a `toUpperCase` method on that because it might be a `number` or a `boolean`.

It's possible you need `getSomething()` to be generic, but in that case it would really matter what `bar.getValue()` does, and might require either `bar.getValue()`'s signature be modified, or a judicious [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) somewhere inside `getSomething()` where you are assuming the responsibility for verifying something the compiler cannot, and dealing with the consequences if your assertion turns out to be untrue at runtime.  Your answer with `return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo as T;` is unlikely to be the right sort of assertion, especially in light of literal types.  I won't speculate further on this approach though.  Suffice it to say that you'll need to think carefully about what claims you make when you use type assertions to make compiler errors go away.

---

Okay, hope that helps!  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#code/MYewdgzgLgBARgQwE4wLwwN4wOYFMoBqCANgK64BcMAFAB5XRICWY2AlA1M6zAD4xhSAWzi4U-OCBDFcCMHxikwAE1wAzFrmVoAfDACMAJgDMAFgCsMAL4BuALAAoR6Eiw8UAMogh+ABYtsNBgECABPMGAAHgAVGFxaKFwVCBhGAIVJaVl5fkERMR1HGGKaAGtcUM5ubAAaGFU1BFJiQhJyKmiOGAAFJG8mCFwYvVQ9DCKSl2gYNSkgxCQAOnciMlxqACJZkA22GxgAegOYJHxSJHkoUIAHXBgBxRV1TWVeNNZeTJk5XjzRJAmxVOUHO8m2aFQ6CUDReMAA-PV1E0WqtyDAqNt7A4SodjtEbncAOTvQK5YT-DJSb45GDRQn3FJgECwEIQJjYMAIOAyGBQEC8gkwQl0xaOKyOZzgaaMIIAWQQUF8iyQcmU3mobEWfI8XACGqx7i8PkVeo2iAAXhs6oxNYqktQAG66GBTLKLYggbCOrUgACq11uSAAwiF1mxw1ijrSCQBRJB9JBUB0+-2BkODBkCZnBGZKYBQJjgGAShxTWDXIKG7x+U0AR1ItCtMA2tzkpFgcHbiRQqpgACtcMRiKFdpHjmWYNcqL1+oNIi3su34F2xMEVP3B8ONoUnLuJ1Xjf5WIYgiFwsAyhUqgE6g1ka01teeGT8uJ4FTshxAT0+kIBkMSQUP5VwkD85BGMZvwncF0AWZZ8FRdYtikUdi2xEpgVBGY5khKEng0MAtHhRFGmaB80QxKQsXFBwDxrY9NgtJsbS1Xx7SdUYXSlN0PS9ZM+VTMR0zDCNcTieMQCQABCRwowAWgUxSlOUlTVLU9S9AAP20nTdM02TjhnQMriFASAyE0N6TVXBGWzeIBlgIsrluIVgKQQlRV3EtHCAA)

Answer (score 0):

I had to cast `foo as T`

change

```
return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo;
```

to

```
return foo === undefined ? defaultValue : foo as T;
```

I am not sure why I will need this explicit casting as `foo` is definitely `T` since it is not undefined. 
And `T` is constrained to type `string | boolean | number`

Comment: See comment above explaining why such casting could be harmful